# Calling method of a child component if parent has two children of the same component

Tags: angular, typescript

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-view-child

so according to the "official" docs, calling method of child component can be done inside the parent's Class using:

```
@ViewChild(CountdownTimerComponent)
private timerComponent: CountdownTimerComponent;
```

and doing

```
timerComponent.methodName()
```

So what if the parent component uses two CountDownTimerComponent and only to want to call timerComponentNumber1.methodName()?

Assuming the developer wants to call the method inside the ParentClass and not from template

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `@ViewChildren` instead

```
@ViewChildren(CountdownTimerComponent)
private timerComponents: QueryList<CountdownTimerComponent>;
```

You may iterate over `timerComponents` and invoke the method you want; or do something like this:

```
this.timerComponents.toArray()[0].someMethod();
```

Here is the reference to [the documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewChildren-decorator.html).